# Service stops running after closing the app

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have written a simple service in Android. Its running as long as the app is running and stops when the application is closed. My codes are as follows:

```
public class WitoService extends Service {
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
}
```

}

Manifest file entry

```
<service android:name=".WitoService"/>
```

service calling code:

```
if(!serviceRunning) {
        startService(new Intent(this, WitoService.class));
        serviceRunning=true;
    }else {
        stopService(new Intent(this, WitoService.class));
        serviceRunning=false;
    }

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal behavior when your application target larger than android O. To keep your service alive should make foregroud service and notice user by notification. You can check here 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.